# TextField Update with setInterval in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am quite new on javascript and jquery. I have implemented the following simple code to update the textfield with random values with every 5 seconds. However, it does not update.

Please do not offend if the question is so simple for you.

```
  <input type="text" value="Hello there" id="me"/><br/>

   self.init = function () {
        $("#me").val(setInterval(myFunction(),5000));
    }

    function myFunction() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }
```

Comment: setInterval will run after (5 seconds) you attempt to set the value. Instead, try setInterval(function(){$('#me').val(myFunction())}, 5000)

Comment: I could not get your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it's done.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $("#me").val(myFunction());
}, 5000);

function myFunction() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Hello there" id="me" />
```

Comment: That is great! SOF does not allow me to accept your answer right away. I should wait 10 min. Thanks a lot Preston.